# Using a system supplied NSValueTransformer on a transformable Core Data attribute

Tags: cocoa, core-data

When trying to use a system supplied `NSValueTransformer` in Core Data I get the following warning:

```
Warning: no NSValueTransformer with class name 'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName' was found for attribute 'someAttribute' on entity 'SomeEntity'
```

How come the `NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformer` is not recognized?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out that the actual string that the `NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformer` points too  for this transformer is `NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData`. But even more importantly: if you specify this, the transformer will be used in the wrong direction. Leave the transformer name field empty to use `NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformer` correctly.

Comment: You get "+[_PFRoutines encodeObjectValue:forTransformableAttribute:](2295): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to find an instance of NSValueTransformer registered for the name:" if you use CD + iCloud. So none of this is true. you better off with your own transformer.